# How to optimize and reduce database calls?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm calculating totals on the fly for a project but it is currently quite database intensive:

```
def sub_total(package)
  subtotal = 0.0
  self.quote_items.order("area_id").each do |item|
    subtotal += Unit.find(item.unit_id).highest_price(package)*item.quantity if item.unit
  end
  sprintf("%.2f", sub_total)
end
```

In Unit model:

```
def highest_price(package)
  highest_price = 0
  highest_id = 0
  self.options.where("options.id IN (SELECT option_id FROM options_packages WHERE package_id = '#{package.id}')").each do |option|
    if (option.price > highest_price)
      highest_price = option.price
      highest_id = option.id
    end
  end
  Quote.add_margin highest_price
end
```

At each iteration, it queries the database in the Unit.find method.

How can this be optimised?  I'd appreciate any help or advice to clean this up!  This project uses Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated price - this seems a bit more efficient for calculating the highest_price ... ?

```
highest_price = self.options.where("options.id IN (SELECT option_id FROM options_packages WHERE package_id = '#{package.id}')").order('price DESC').first.price
Quote.add_margin highest_price
```

Comment: Since you only need the highest price, you can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query, after the `ORDER BY` (I'm not sure how to do that from Rails' ORM). As for the performance, I think you don't need the subquery, you could use a join. But, again, I can't help you with crafting this with Rails. If you post your DB structure, I can help you build a raw SQL query.

Comment: thanks - it is currently applying LIMIT 1 through the use of the 'first' syntax

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with ruby, but I think you can get the max price directly from SQL. Something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(price) 
FROM options_packages 
WHERE package_id = "#{package.id}" 
GROUP BY package_id
```